# How to avoid creating duplicate Cloudwatch Event Rule?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

From a SNS topic, we get the information regarding when an event is about to start. Based on the time received, a CloudWatch Rule is created that would invoke a Lambda function at the time.

At a later time, we can receive an updated time for the same event. So, we either need to update the CRON expression of the existing Cloudwatch Event Rule or we have to delete the existing rule and create a new one.

How to achieve this? How to prevent duplication of CloudWatch Event Rule for the same rule? How to ensure that only one rule exists for a event and that has the updated time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html

“If you are updating an existing rule, the rule is replaced with what you specify in this PutRule command. If you omit arguments in PutRule, the old values for those arguments are not kept. Instead, they are replaced with null values.”